# How do I upload videos using the Ubuntu One apps?

Tags: ubuntu-one, video, android

Love the app for my android phone and iPad. I take a picture, it's on my PC and laptop. Brilliant. Only problem is that this doesn't work for videos.

Is this a known issue with the ubuntuone app? If so, when can I expect to upload videos from my android phone and iPad. The iPad dropbox app can do videos and that's the only reason that I still use it.

Excellent work so far, please please please fix video uploads

Comment: Are you referring to the Ubuntu One Files app for Android here?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu One apps for both Android and iOS both allow the upload of videos. However, there is not yet the option to automatically upload videos as there currently is with photos.

**For Android:**
If you wish to upload a video you can easily do it manually:

- Open the Ubuntu One app and press the add button

[image]

- Select **Add video** and navigate to the video file that you wish to
  upload.